# mustache doesn't render any nested objects in the row

Tags: multidimensional-array, nested, mustache

I'm trying to render an object with nested docs. The problem is it's only displaying entries from r.lang.x and not r.offerHistorys.offerHistory.x but the row is rendered just empty but for the lang values.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hy6yn/83/

**mustache.js 2.2**

```
Mustache.to_html(this.templates.openRequest, r, this.templates.partials);
```

**log r (data passed to template)**

```
    {
   "header":{
      "index":"/shiftadmin/_design/shifts/_list/index/shifts?descending=true&limit=10",
      "appTitle":"Shift-Admin-Open-Requests"
   },
   "scripts":{

   },
   "lang":{
      "prio":"priority",
      "incentive":"incentive",
      "stat":"stat",
      "yourOffers":"yourOffers",
      "yourReqs":"yourReqs",
      "offerHistory":"offerHistory",
      "pageTitle":"pageTitle"
   },
   "offerHistorys":[
      {
         "offerHistory":{
            "_id":"83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d032106",
            "_rev":"11-d34b8b430e221a3dff5d73f6a1420e40",
            "type":"offer",
            "shifts":[
               "83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d001aa2"
            ],
            "idUser":1,
            "prio":1,
            "desc":"desc of offer",
            "money":null,
            "status":"requested",
            "idTarget":6,
            "created_at":"2016-11-01 00:00 +02:00",
            "shift":[
               {
                  "_id":"83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d001aa2",
                  "_rev":"8-a98d5b16296cc7d325210b58303ee2eb",
                  "cat":"test",
                  "title":"2 server test",
                  "idUser":2,
                  "idQualification":16,
                  "idSection":1,
                  "type":"shift",
                  "start":"2016-11-20 14:00 +02:00",
                  "end":"2016-11-20 23:00 +02:00",
                  "created_at":"2016-11-01 00:00 +02:00"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "offerHistory":{
            "_id":"83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d032457",
            "_rev":"9-72942be560e22b3788afcaa5a85c2fa3",
            "type":"offer",
            "shifts":[
               "83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d002c7q"
            ],
            "idUser":1,
            "prio":1,
            "desc":"desc of offer",
            "money":5,
            "status":"requested",
            "idTarget":5,
            "created_at":"2016-11-01 00:00 +02:00",
            "shift":[
               {
                  "_id":"83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d002c7q",
                  "_rev":"8-1bb6b9a995b7db3b1af5802a23dd5efc",
                  "cat":"test",
                  "title":"3 server test",
                  "idUser":3,
                  "idQualification":16,
                  "idSection":2,
                  "type":"shift",
                  "start":"2016-11-21 14:00 +02:00",
                  "end":"2016-11-21 23:00 +02:00",
                  "created_at":"2016-11-01 00:00 +02:00"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**templates/openRequest.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ pageTitle }}</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-0"></div>
<div class="col-md-8" id="historyCont">
    <h1>{{lang.offerHistory}}T</h1>
    <div class="tabs row">
       <button class="btn bg-info active" 
               type="button" 
               onclick="showHistory('offers')">{{lang.yourOffers}}                                                                          
       </button>  
       <button class="btn bg-info" 
               type="button" 
               onclick="showHistory(reqs)">{{lang.yourReqs}}
       </button>
    </div>
    <div id="tblOfferHist"></div>
    <div id="tblReqHist"></div>
</div>
{{#offerHistorys}}
    {{>offerHistory}}
{{/offerHistorys}}
</body>
</html>
```

**templates/partials/offerHistory.html**

```
    <div class="hand {{gHistoryStat[status].bg}} row" id="historyItem{{_id}}" onclick="togNots(this)">
    <span class="glyphicon {{gHistoryStat[status].icon}} col-xs-1 historyIcon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{status}}">{{reqBy}}</span>
{{#shift}}
    <span class="col-xs-10 historyTxt"><b>{{title}}</b> <span class="right small">{{lang.putInAt}} {{strSent}}</span><br>
        {{start}} {{end}}<br>
{{/shift}}
        {{shift[0].start}}
        {{shift.start}}
        {{lang.priority}}: {{lang.prio}} {{prio}}<br>
        {{lang.incentives}}: {{money}}<br>
        {{lang.stat}}: {{status}}
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently there are limits to nested levels or i had a logic error in my code. I got it to work by using one html template and reducing the nested level in data

```
var data = {
   "header":{
      "index":"/shiftadmin/_design/shifts/_list/index/shifts?descending=true&limit=10",
      "appTitle":"Shift-Admin-Open-Requests"
   },
   "scripts":{

   },
   "lang":{
      "prio":"priority",
      "incentive":"incentive",
      "stat":"Status",
      "yourOffers":"yourOffers",
      "yourReqs":"yourReqs",
      "offerHistory":"offerHistory",
      "pageTitle":"pageTitle"
   },
   "offerHistorys":[
      {

            "_id":"83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d032106",
            "_rev":"11-d34b8b430e221a3dff5d73f6a1420e40",
            "type":"offer",
            "shifts":[
               "83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d001aa2"
            ],
            "idUser":1,
            "prio":1,
            "desc":"desc of offer",
            "money":null,
            "status":"requested",
            "idTarget":6,
            "created_at":"2016-11-01 00:00 +02:00",
            "shift":[
               {
                  "_id":"83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d001aa2",
                  "_rev":"8-a98d5b16296cc7d325210b58303ee2eb",
                  "cat":"test",
                  "title":"2 server test",
                  "idUser":2,
                  "idQualification":16,
                  "idSection":1,
                  "type":"shift",
                  "start":"2016-11-20 14:00 +02:00",
                  "end":"2016-11-20 23:00 +02:00",
                  "created_at":"2016-11-01 00:00 +02:00"
               }
            ]

      },
      {

            "_id":"83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d032457",
            "_rev":"9-72942be560e22b3788afcaa5a85c2fa3",
            "type":"offer",
            "shifts":[
               "83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d002c7q"
            ],
            "idUser":1,
            "prio":1,
            "desc":"desc of offer",
            "money":5,
            "status":"requested",
            "idTarget":5,
            "created_at":"2016-11-01 00:00 +02:00",
            "shift":[
               {
                  "_id":"83c6a87147479fe3408a3d951d002c7q",
                  "_rev":"8-1bb6b9a995b7db3b1af5802a23dd5efc",
                  "cat":"test",
                  "title":"3 server test",
                  "idUser":3,
                  "idQualification":16,
                  "idSection":2,
                  "type":"shift",
                  "start":"2016-11-21 14:00 +02:00",
                  "end":"2016-11-21 23:00 +02:00",
                  "created_at":"2016-11-01 00:00 +02:00"
               }
            ]

      }
   ]
};

var openRequest = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>{{ pageTitle }}</title></head><body><div class="col-md-2 col-xs-0"></div><div class="col-md-8" id="historyCont"><h1>{{lang.offerHistory}}</h1><div class="tabs row"><button class="btn bg-info active" type="button" onclick="showHistory(\'offers\')">{{lang.yourOffers}}</button>  <button class="btn bg-info" type="button" onclick="showHistory(reqs)">{{lang.yourReqs}}</button></div><div id="tblOfferHist"></div><div id="tblReqHist"></div></div>{{#offerHistorys}}<div class="hand {{gHistoryStat[status].bg}} row" id="historyItem{{_id}}" onclick="togNots(this)"><span class="glyphicon {{gHistoryStat[status].icon}} col-xs-1 historyIcon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{status}}">{{reqBy}}</span>{{#shift}}<span class="col-xs-10 historyTxt"><b>{{title}}</b> <span class="right small">{{lang.putInAt}} {{strSent}}</span><br>{{start}} {{end}}<br>{{/shift}}{{shift[0].start}}{{shift.start}}{{lang.prio}}: {{lang.prio}} {{prio}}<br>{{lang.incentive}}: {{money}}<br>{{lang.stat}}: {{status}}</span></div>{{/offerHistorys}}</body></html>';

$(document).ready(function () {
  var html = Mustache.to_html(openRequest, data);
  console.log(html)
  $("#contenet").html(html)
})
```